# AWK sum every two rows

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to sum two rows until end of file:

```
1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 4 5 6
2 3 5 6
```

Output should be

```
1 3 5 7
2 7 10 12
```

I have tried the following, but it only works for the 1st row

```
awk '{s+=$1}NR%2==0{print s;s=0}' testfileForSum.txt
```

Comment: I have tried following but this works for only 1st row  awk '{s+=$1}NR%2==0{print s;s=0}' testfileForSum.txt

Comment: Are there always four elements in a row?

Comment: They are 7 elements but cannot it be generic for N elements

Comment: Of course it can. - But that N is fixed for each line throughout the whole data file?

Comment: yes N is fixed for each line throughput the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR%2 { split($0, a) ; next }
  { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", a[i]+$i ; print "" }
'
```

Explanation: For lines with even number (`NR%2`) it will memorize the fields of the current line in an array `a`. And for the other (odd) lines there will be an iteration over the fields, and the sum of the respective memorized field `a[i]` and current field `$i` printed.

Comment: As I am knew to awk and this forum can you also explain the above solution as it will help me in future

Comment: Doesnot seem to work on the following data. Seems to be an issue of the range. Works perfect otherwise.   845737163  5471453703
6945297424  44092072061
816281003  5704419737
6248800314  42808172792

Comment: @RajaKashif; Might be a integer range issue with your awk on your platform. - Should work with GNU awk. - What version of awk do you use and on which platform?

Comment: mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

Comment: I installed gawk and that solved the problem. Thanks @Janis